# How to conditionally append a url parameter to form text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-hooks

I have a form with a single input which is query for the search url -

```
 <form className={styles.searchInputContainer} role="search" action="/search">
          <label htmlFor={id} className={styles.searchLabel}>{constants.search}</label>
          <input id={id} className={styles.searchInput} type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

At the moment, when I hit enter, the url will end with '/search?q=*whatever_the_input_is*'

I am currently doing logic elsewhere in the file to check if the search bar is on a particular page. With this boolean value (`isShoppingPage`), I want to optionally append a 'type=shop' to the url when the user hits enter so it automatically only searches through the shop categories. I've tried appending 'type=shop' to the input value but then the url ends up having URL encoding. I'm confused as to how to conditionally add this without changing the `name="q"` which the input currently has and needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `action` you can use `onSubmit` prop of the `form`.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Form = (props) => {
  const {styles, id, constants} = props;
  const [qValue, setQValue] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // here you can make API call with q=qValue and type=shop
  };

  return (
    <form className={styles.searchInputContainer} role="search" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor={id} className={styles.searchLabel}>{constants.search}</label>
      <input id={id} className={styles.searchInput} type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" value={qValue} onChange={e => setQValue(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  )

};
```

This is [guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) from react docs